# ActionBar show and hide different effects on Android 4.1 and Android 4.0-

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

My application uses ActionBarSherlock to show and hide the action bar.

On Android 4.1+ the action bar slides up and goes out of the scren (which is the animation I need) on hide (And the opposite on show) but on Android 4.0 or lower the effect is a opacity fade out.

What is the best way to get the same effect as on Android 4.1, with the slide?

UPDATE:
I went to hide() implementation and look into the Sherlock method. In this method `mContentView` is checked to see if it's null.

`mContentView` is only set if we don't have `windowActionBarOverlay`set to `true`:

```
if ((features & (1 << Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY)) == 0) {
        mContentView = (NineFrameLayout)decor.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    }
```

In fact, If I delete the ActionBarOverlay option, all versions use the same effect to hide and show the action bar, but I need to put this to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the implementation with or without actionbarsherlock will not be different in this use case. Since you are using 4.0 and 4.1. The animations will rely on the animations provided by the SDK and not ActionBarSherlock.

Currently you have 2 animations one from 4.0 and one from 4.1. These are the steps required to get the same animation:

- Find out where the animation is called
- Find the animation from 4.1 and import into your project
- Set that animation to be called when Actionbar is shown/hidden
- That animation will be called for 4.0 and for 4.1+

I'm not sure what will happen on pre 3.0 devices,

Hope this helps, else comment below

Comment: I will update my post with the information related to this answer, thank you for your help.